# How to access system file indexes in headless chrome through selenium?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I try to access my downloads folder in normal chrome through selenium it works fine and I get an indexed version of my downloads folder in the browser.
[What the downloads page looks like in the browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvtbZ.png)

But when I run my test in headless chrome with screenshots it seems that the downloads page is never reached. The code that runs is:

```
    def go_to_downloads_page(self):
    """Go to Downloads page index."""
    self.driver.get("file:///C:/Users/Muhammad Ali/Downloads/")
```

Upon execution of this method this is what shows up in my debugging console:

```
...
[0720/173049.601:INFO:CONSOLE(8)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined", source: file:///C:/Users/Muhammad%20Ali/Downloads/ (8)
[0720/173049.602:INFO:CONSOLE(9)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined", source: file:///C:/Users/Muhammad%20Ali/Downloads/ (9)
[0720/173049.602:INFO:CONSOLE(10)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined", source: file:///C:/Users/Muhammad%20Ali/Downloads/ (10)
[0720/173049.602:INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined", source: file:///C:/Users/Muhammad%20Ali/Downloads/ (11)
[0720/173049.603:INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined", source: file:///C:/Users/Muhammad%20Ali/Downloads/ (12)
[0720/173049.603:INFO:CONSOLE(13)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined", source: file:///C:/Users/Muhammad%20Ali/Downloads/ (13)
[0720/173049.604:INFO:CONSOLE(14)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined", source: file:///C:/Users/Muhammad%20Ali/Downloads/ (14)
[0720/173049.604:INFO:CONSOLE(15)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined", source: file:///C:/Users/Muhammad%20Ali/Downloads/ (15)
[0720/173049.604:INFO:CONSOLE(16)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined", source: file:///C:/Users/Muhammad%20Ali/Downloads/ (16)
...
```

The test fails on the next bit of code that is executed since it contains a find_element() and no elements exist; the screenshot that is returned is [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ppIq.png)

Does anyone know why this is happening and what the workaround is?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.driver.get("file:///C:/Users/Muhammad Ali/Downloads/")
```

Try with the address inside quotes.

Comment: My bad I messed up in the question. The address is in quotes but it still doesn't work, i'll edit the question.